# Which is the secure way to disable the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form and enabling the submit button after fill the all the fields in the form. I used jquery to disable the button also use the `disabled="disabled"` in the submit button. Now I am on the browser and button is showing disabled.

Now What I did, Right clicked and inspect elements and goes to my register button and  I remove the `disabled=" disabled"` from the HTML and my button got enable without filling the details and I clicked no button form submitted.

I just want to know Is there any other solution to handle this issue? because anyone can enable this and access it without filling the form.

Would you help me out in this?

[image]

```js
(function() {
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {
        var empty = false;
        $('form > input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });
        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})()
```

```html
<form>
    Username<br />
    <input type="text" id="user_input" name="username" /><br />
    Password<br />
    <input type="password" id="pass_input" name="password" /><br />
    Email<br />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />     
    <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is impossible to make the front end secure in that way, which is why it's always important to add server side validation

Comment: @user184994, Thanks for the reply, That I know to add the server side validation. I thought there is some another way to handle it.

Comment: The only way is using server side handling

Answer (score 2):

The disabled property is good but its more or less cosmetics.

There is a simple way to prevent a form submit using JavaScript submit Event handler. You check for a condition to be met - otherwise you **cancel** the submission.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent form submit by simply modifying your function to this:

```
(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });
    if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

})()